# Ajax has been executed when page is reload but just have to be executed with click event

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a problem that I did an ajax to be executed just when the user click in a link, and this is been executed too every time that the page is reloaded

follow the code:

```
<h:commandLink id="botaoFecharModal" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" >
     <f:ajax onevent="fecha" event="click" listener="#{itemController.atualizaRegraNegocio()}" render=":Objetoform:pgTabela"/>
     <i class="icon-ok"></i>
     Concluir
</h:commandLink>
```

Somebody knows what i have to do for this stop?

Comment: Did you declare the `f:` namespace in top of template as `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`?

Comment: For the event on reload you might use the `preRenderView` event (http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/)